# Apache POI - access and modify custom fields

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working with apache POI.
Is it possible to define so called custom fields (see Quickpat menu) with apache POI?
I'm using objects of type XWPF to access docx files since my program.
I haven't found anything in apache doc POI? Have you got any hints about
that issue?

Thank.

Comment: I guess you mean the [Quick Parts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-quick-parts-and-autotext-in-word-and-outlook-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813) menu? None of this is supported by `XWPF` until now. But of course there are the `Office Open XML`-schema classes which could be used. But your question is too broad. What exactly do you want do do? Which exact field do you want to insert into a `XWPFDocument`? Or is your question about reading fields? The question is too vague as it is now.

Comment: The file i want to insert in a XWPFDocument is a ms word 2016 DOCX. I'd like read and write custom fields included into a word file with POI.

Comment: Are those indications helpful?

Comment: Always nor too broad. We need **one** concrete problem to write an answer here. Which exact kind of field do you want to insert into a `XWPFDocument`? That could be answered. And from this answer you might generalize to other fields then. Which exact kind of field do you want to read from a `XWPFDocument`? That could be answered. And ...